# How to store 128-bit value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to convert a UUID (NSUUID, unique string, 128-bit) to a number and store it in SQLite (as primary key uses Core Data).

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to much on the interwebs that does what you are looking for, so I would guess that what you desire to do may not be the smartest thing to do.

All I could really find was:

[How to store 128 bit values](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/How-to-store-128-bit-values-tt25224.html#none)

[[sqlite] 128-bit numbers](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/11908)

Everything else seems to talk about text instead of numbers

---

As per the comment from Drew, the second link is now dead.  However I found it in the wayback machine:

[Wayback machine version of: [sqlite] 128-bit numbers](https://web.archive.org/web/20151127022649/http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/11908)

The key bits from that discussion are:

> On Tue, 2005-05-03 at 17:52 -0400, Christopher Petrilli wrote:
>
> > I'm wondering if the availability of 128-bit numbers has ever been
> >     contemplated? The reason I'm asking is that I have an application that
> >     needs to store IPv6 addresses, which are 128bits.  Right now, I'm
> >     storing them in 2 64-bit fields, but this obviously complicates the
> >     query quite a bit.
>
> Declare the field as CLOB or TEXT and store the numbers that way.  You
>   can store any size number you want in a TEXT column.  You just cannot
>   do arithmetic on them if they are bigger than 64 bits.  Do you need to
>   do arithmetic on your IPv6 addresses?

and

> SQLite lets you do range comparisons on a BLOB.  It uses memcmp() to
>   do the comparisons.  So as long as you insert your data in a format
>   that can be compared correctly using memcmp() you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The data type `binary(128)` will allow for a 128bit value.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data has no concept of a primary keys and does not necessarily use SQLite as a backing store, so this is not possible.

When you want to convert an UUID string to binary, use

```
uuid_t uuid;
NSUUID *uuidString = [[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067"] autorelease];
[uuidString getUUIDBytes:uuid];
```